# Java look and feel JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jtabbedpane

I'm using a JTabbedPane in a project of mine, and I am trying to change the look and feel of the application. When I set the windows look and feel (and any other look and feel for that matter), all the buttons, check buttons etc change to what they should look like, but the tabs still look like the default swing tabs. Here's an example of what it looks like:

[image]

The buttons and checkbox look like windows components, but the tabs look like the default swing. If it helps, I'm using a subclass of JTabbedPane that is defined in a separate class file. My question is how can I get the tabs in the JTabbedPane to look like windows tabs?

This code emulates the problem for me. The tabs show up as swing but the buttons show up as a different l&f:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class TabbedFrame
{
    private static JFrame window;
    private static JPanel pane;
    private static JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    public static void main(String[] vars) 
    {
        try
        {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception ee){
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
        window = new JFrame("tabs");
        pane = new JPanel();
        window.setSize(200, 300);
        window.setLocation(100, 100);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setContentPane(pane);    
        Panel[] panes;
        panes = new Panel[2];
        panes[0] = new Panel();
        panes[1] = new Panel();
        panes[0].add(new Label("PANEL 1..................."));
        panes[1].add(new Label("PANEL 2 ....."));   
        tabs.addTab("tab 1", panes[0]);
        tabs.addTab("tab 2", panes[1]);
        tabs.setSize(480, 640);
        pane.add(tabs);
        pane.add(new JButton("test"));
        pane.add(new JCheckBox());
        pane.add(new JRadioButton());
        tabs.setBounds(20, 20, 200, 200);
        window.setVisible(true);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Is something else explicitly setting the look and feel of the tabs? What UI class is the JTabbedPane showing?

Comment: Works in [`TabComponentsDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html#eg). Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: thanks to whoever edited the image in

@JeffStorey - it is the default swing look and feel

Comment: Also nothing else is setting the l&f as far as I know.

Comment: `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");`  Motif?!?  Going for that 1980s 'retro' feel?  Yuck!

Comment: @AndrewThompson it was just for the example, but ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `JTabbedPane` is created before the PLAF is set.  There are at least two fixes.

1. Move the line that creates the tabbed pane into the `main`, and put it after the call to set the PLAF.
2. Call `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(topLevelContainer)` as shown in the [Nested Layout Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556).  That example allows the PLAF to be changed by the user at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of UIManager settings that you can use to manage the look and feel for your JTabbedPane. The link below gives all the properties that you can use to customize the look and feel for the JTabbedPane.

[Customizing JTabbedPane look and feel](http://books.google.com/books?id=YPjZNlEgAMcC&pg=PA401&lpg=PA401&dq=customizing%20a%20jtabbedpane%20look%20and%20feel&source=bl&ots=GO7qm-bYd8&sig=8nlhhzZsrJXmo0UZePKcHZ_L4z0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iWsHUP3RCIW70QHr_cXJAw&ved=0CGQQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=customizing%20a%20jtabbedpane%20look%20and%20feel&f=false)

For example you can use to customize the color as:

```
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", Color.RED);
```

The JTabbedPane has already been instantiated in the code posted so the UIManager settings have no change.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class TabbedFrame
{
private static JFrame window;
private static JPanel pane;
private static JTabbedPane tabs;
public static void main(String[] vars) 
{
    try
    {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");
            UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected",Color.GREEN);

    } catch (Exception ee){
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }
    window = new JFrame("tabs");
    pane = new JPanel();
    tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    window.setSize(200, 300);
    window.setLocation(100, 100);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setContentPane(pane);    
    Panel[] panes;
    panes = new Panel[2];
    panes[0] = new Panel();
    panes[1] = new Panel();
    panes[0].add(new Label("PANEL 1..................."));
    panes[1].add(new Label("PANEL 2 ....."));   
    tabs.addTab("tab 1", panes[0]);
    tabs.addTab("tab 2", panes[1]);
    tabs.setSize(480, 640);
    pane.add(tabs);
    pane.add(new JButton("test"));
    pane.add(new JCheckBox());
    pane.add(new JRadioButton());
    tabs.setBounds(20, 20, 200, 200);
    window.setVisible(true);    
}
```

}

Comment: When I do that, nothing changes as far as I can tell. the tabs still look like the default swing ones.